# React nattive multi select , cant select multiple values

Tags: react-native, multi-select

I've an api which is resolving into an array of objects, something like this

```
[
{flagUrl : 'http://....' , name : India , id : 7},
{flagUrl : 'http://....' , name : USA , id : 2},
{flagUrl : 'http://....' , name : Australia , id : 8},
....
]
```

and then Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-select-multiple , this package to make a multi selectable list from above link.

What i want is , firstly I can display the list of country in which user can select lets say two countries ( i can control max select with the prop provided ) and then I want when user goes to next page, I can get what id user has selected in previous screen. 
Currently i tried to display the same and its just the list of countries that i can show right now and then I cant get their ids. Here's what i tried so far

```
<SelectMultiple
        items={this.state.countryList.map((x) => x.name)}
        selectedItems={this.state.selectedCountries}
        onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange}
        maxSelect={2}
        />
```

where my `countrylist` has the above array and here are the functions that i've used

```
onSelectionsChange = (selectedCountries) => {
    this.setState({ selectedCountries })
  }
```

and `selectedItems` is just an empty array in my state.

So I just want to render a list of countries, user selects few of them and then i can send the country's selected ids to the next screen via `this.props.navigate...` 
Let me know if you need additional information on this.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your country list must be label and value like

```
 <SelectMultiple
     items={this.state.countryList.map((x) => ({ name: x.name, value:x.id })}
     selectedItems={this.state.selectedCountries}
     onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange}
     maxSelect={2}
 />
```

the onSelectionsChange method should be the same

```
onSelectionsChange = (selectedCountries) => {
    this.setState({ selectedCountries })
}
```

Then when you want to move to another screen then

```
 moveToAnotherPage =() => {
   const { selectedCountries } = this.state;
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   const ids = selectedCountries.map(item => item.value);
   navigation.navigate('ScreenName', {ids});
  }
```

Comment: this seems to be correct thing, but im getting map of undefined error again , ( again as in i tried this earlier as well ) . So its seems like its unable to map through the values , i even logged the country list and seems like it has the array inside it
0:
id: 17
name: "Bangladesh"
flag_url: 'url' and so on

Comment: please console this on the render method and see

this.state.countryList.map((x) => ({ name: x.name, value:x.id })

Comment: Yea sorry my bad, i didn't resolve the api on did mount while refactoring, done now and works like charm, marking as solution. Thanks man

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!